# Spring Integration Jdbc OutboundGateway returning 1 record ONLY even with MaxRows(0)

Tags: spring-integration

Have an application which has some 30,000+ records in a table and for an analytic use-case we need to fetch all and keep iterating over the returned result for some computation. However, the `Jdbc OutboundGateway` is returning **ONLY 1 record even with `MaxRows(0)`** though there are 30,000+ records in the DB. The same returns n number of records as a `List` when we explicitly set the `MaxRows()` with a non-zero value.

Please share how this can be made to return all rows with `MaxRows(0)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably how your JDBC driver works or how your RDBMS is configured for `maxRows`.

The logic there in `JdbcOutboundGateway` is like this:

```
    if (this.maxRows != null) {
        Assert.notNull(this.poller, "If you want to set 'maxRows', then you must provide a 'selectQuery'.");
        this.poller.setMaxRows(this.maxRows);
    }
```

where that `JdbcPollingChannelAdapter` has this logic:

1. By default it is   `private int maxRows = 0;`
2. ```
    return new PreparedStatementCreatorWithMaxRows(preparedStatementCreator,
                        JdbcPollingChannelAdapter.this.maxRows);
   ```
3. And that one:

   ```
        public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection con) throws SQLException {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = this.delegate.createPreparedStatement(con);
            preparedStatement.setMaxRows(this.maxRows); // We can't mutate provided JdbOperations for this option
            return preparedStatement;
        }
   ```
4. Then `PreparedStatement`:

   ```
         /**
     * Sets the limit for the maximum number of rows that any
     * {@code ResultSet} object  generated by this {@code Statement}
     * object can contain to the given number.
     * If the limit is exceeded, the excess
     * rows are silently dropped.
     *
     * @param max the new max rows limit; zero means there is no limit
     * @throws SQLException if a database access error occurs,
     * this method is called on a closed {@code Statement}
     *            or the condition {@code max >= 0} is not satisfied
     * @see #getMaxRows
     */
    void setMaxRows(int max) throws SQLException;
   ```

> zero means there is no limit

The logic in the `JdbcOutboundGateway` in the end is like this:

```
if (list.size() == 1 && (this.maxRows == null || this.maxRows == 1)) {
        payload = list.get(0);
}
```

So, we return one record only if `ResultSet` has only one element.

I doubt we can do anything from Spring Integration perspective, unless you want to try with an `Integer.MAX_VALUE` for this property since your JDBC communication does not honor `PreparedStatement.setMaxRows()` contract.

Comment: Thanks Artem, we will proceed with `Integer.MAX_VALUE` which sounds a better option than debugging the Jdbc driver. In the case where we are able to get all the 30k+ records, will it be a resultset returned or all the 30k+ records as java objects (which might kill our memory)?

Comment: Your observation is correct: the `JdbcOutboundGateway` fetches all of them into a memory. You can implement a custom Service Activator calling `JdbcOperations.queryForStream()` manually instead. Feel free to raise a GH issue to add a streaming support into a `JdbcPollingChannelAdapter`.

Comment: thank you, https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/3963

Comment: aggregate() seems to be not working with Stream `split()` via `JdbcOperations.queryForStream()`, can you please suggest?

Comment: Yeah... We don't explain that in the docs, but `Stream` doesn't have a `size` to make a default aggregator working: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/message-routing.html#iterators. You need to look into some custom `releaseStrategy`. More over this looks fully as a new SO thread.

Comment: Yes, have started https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74985873/spring-integration-jdbcoperations-queryforstream-split-and-aggregate