# Spring Integration JdbcOperations.queryForStream() - split and aggregate

Tags: spring-integration

We are using `JdbcOperations.queryForStream()` to fetch 30k+ rows from database as per the inputs from [Spring Integration Jdbc OutboundGateway returning 1 record ONLY even with MaxRows(0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74729365/spring-integration-jdbc-outboundgateway-returning-1-record-only-even-with-maxrow), however `split()` and `aggregate()` on the stream is not working. We need the aggregation to work as to know when all the stream records are consumed to perform a final operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The splitter doesn't know the size for an `Iterator`, `Stream` or `Flux` request message payloads: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/message-routing.html#iterators. Therefore a `sequenceSize` header is `0` and default aggregator cannot do its job just because there is no `sequenceSize` to compare with. You must provide a custom `releaseStrategy` or rely on a `groupTimeout` to perform that final operation.

Another trick could be done with JDBC: before calling `queryForStream()` you can ask for count of records and set that value into some header in a reply message before splitter. Such a header you can use in a custom `releaseStrategy`.

See more info about aggregator features in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/message-routing.html#aggregator

Comment: Thank you, it explains. Shall try the custom `releaseStrategy` option